# JavaScript fetch response.status or response.text() though not both

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have two `fetch` scripts that work great at either or though I can't figure out how to combine them.

This first one allows me to know what the `response.status` is however even though it somehow knows the server's HTTP response while not having the response body (yeah, asynchronous):

```
fetch(url).then(function(r)
{
 if (r.status != 200) {alert('Error: unable to load preview, HTTP response '+r.status+'.');}
 else
 {
  console.log(r.text());//Promise { <state>: "pending" }, no good.
 }
}).catch(function(err) {alert('Error: '+err);});
```

This second script allows me to access the `response.text()` though I have no access to the `response.status`:

```
fetch(url).then(r => r.text()).then(function(r)
{
 console.log(r);//response text.
});
```

How do I combine the scripts properly so I have access to both the `response.status` and `response.text()` *after* the request has been received?

Comment: You can create a funciton at first then handler to do more than just returning r.text()

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Could you post please? If it works I'd be happy to accept/vote.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't expect three answers! I'll *properly* go through everything later tomorrow. Thank you for the help! ︀

Answer (score 1):

```js
    fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search").then(function(r)
    {
     if (r.status != 200) {
        alert('Error: unable to load preview, HTTP response '+r.status+'.');
      return
     }
     r.text().then(txt => console.log(txt))
    }).catch(function(err) {alert('Error: '+err);});
```

You can do it like this; Promise need to be resolved before you can access the value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which allows you to handle many Promise at the same time as `fetch` return a promise.

```
const firstFetch = fetch(url);
const secondFetch = fetch(url);

Promise.all([firstFetch, secondFetch]).then(([firstResponse, secondResponse]) => {
   // Here you can have access to both firstResponse.status

   // And secondResponse.text
    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

while @shubhan's code will work, a cleaner approach may be the built in promise chaining, to avoid callback hell which promises strives to solve:

```js
fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 400) throw { code: response.status }
    return response.text() // if you return a promise in a `then` block, the chained `then` block will get the resolved result
  })
  .then(text => {
    console.log(text)
    // handle successful event
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // if at any stage of the promise chain, if a promise rejects, or throws, it will be caught by the `catch` block
    if (err.code) {
      // handle status error
    } else {
      // handle other errors
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx

```js
    fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search").then(function(r)
    {
     if (r.status != 200) {
        alert('Error: unable to load preview, HTTP response '+r.status+'.');
      return
     }
     r.text().then(txt => console.log(txt))
    }).catch(function(err) {alert('Error: '+err);});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).